# Print previous values

Tags: python, printing

I am looking to print values that were obtained through a previous loop:

for example:

```
x=10
while i < num_of_guesses:
   y = int(input("enter y: ")
   print(x*y)
   i += 1
```

My goal is to print every value obtained again, so the output would look something like this

```
enter y: 1
10
enter y: 2
10
20
enter y: 1.5
10
20
15
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out a way to print the 10 and 20 (in this example) again.
Any solution?

Comment: Everytime you enter a number, calculate the product and append it to a list, and display the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = []

while (i < num_of_guesses):
    y = int(input("enter y: "))
    arr.append(x*y)
    for m in arr:
        print(m)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the users inputs and append to a list, somethig like this:

```
x= 10
i = 0
values = []
while i < 10:
   y = int(input("enter y: "))
   values.append(y*x)
   print('\n'.join([str(v) for v in values]))
   i += 1
```

Output:

```
enter y: 1
10
enter y: 20
10
200
enter y: 2
10
200
20
```